# Magento Attribute (Display Name and actual passed variable)

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

We need to be able to define an attribute for an internal use reference name but pass an alternative variable elsewhere.

For Example:

**Item Condition** (Displayed Internally when creating product):

1. New
2. Refurbished
3. Used

**Alternate Variable Passed**

1. 1000
2. 2000
3. 3000

The marketplace that we feed some of our inventory down requires this field but in the numeric format. Don't want to leave room for mistakes when selecting this.

We will create this attribute field separately and only for this inventory type in the attribute set.

Kudos for an extension that's available that makes this very easy rather than coding specifically each time we have the need.

Thanks in advance for time and responses. It's much appreciated!

** Using Magento 1.8.1

Comment: You may also consider looking/asking this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

When I come across this requirement I make the attribute value, eg, `'New 1000'` then I alter the attribute display .phtml to strip out the `' 1000'`. I don't need to pass this detail to a feed, but in the feed code you could then strip out the `'New '` and just pass the `(int)'1000'`.

Which I admit is not a rigorous solution.

But if you have custom code for the feed you could just add an array to look up the `1000` etc codes - that would at least be more robust notwithstanding the hard coded look up array, but it sounds like you know the codes in advance and they may rarely change.

Contrast that with writing a module to accept the codes from the AdminHtml and store it in a custom database table. << the proper way for sure but maybe not factored into the budget or project lead time.